# Getting build error in tvOS for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I want to use uitableview in tvos to show list of string data but compiler is throughing following errors in generated header:

```
"No type or protocol named 'UITableViewDataSource'"
And "Attempting to use the forward class 'UITableView' as superclass of 'TWOSSelectionTableTVOS'"
```

Even though this code is working is `ios` .

My code structure is as follow :

SelectionTable.swift:

```
import UIKit

class TWOSSelectionTableTVOS : UITableView
{
private var vDataSrc:[String]!

func SetDataSrc (_ pDataSrc:[String])
{
    self.vDataSrc = pDataSrc
}

func UpdateDataSrc (_ pStringList:[String])
{
    self.vDataSrc += pStringList
}

func GetDataSrc () -> [String]
{
    return self.vDataSrc
}
}
```

PaintUI.swift :

```
import UIKit

@objc
class PaintUI: NSObject,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

static let uShared = PaintUI ()

@objc
static func updateUIMessage() {
    
   
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        
        ExecuteInlineSelectionTable ()
    }
}

func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
        return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell (withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        

    cell.textLabel?.text = "hello"
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let viewcontroller: TWIOSViewController!

    viewcontroller = StaticContext.sViewController
    
    
}

public static func ExecuteInlineSelectionTable ()
{
  

    let selectiontable:TWOSSelectionTableTVOS!
  
    
    selectiontable = TWOSSelectionTableTVOS ()
    
    selectiontable.register (UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    selectiontable.dataSource = uShared
    selectiontable.delegate = uShared
    selectiontable.isScrollEnabled = true
  
   // TODO : will add selection table in view heriearchy but currently getting compilation error
}
}
```

And finally  calling PaintUI.updateUIMessage () , it is throughing above errors for tvOS only but in case of ios code is working fine.